# How to access "this" from Uppy's callback event

Tags: vue.js, this, uppy

I'm using the Uppy Vue component library, and following the [docs](https://uppy.io/docs/vue/), I've initialized Uppy by adding it as a computed property.

```js
computed: {
    uppy: () => new Uppy({
        logger: Uppy.debugLogger
    }).use(AwsS3Multipart, {
        limit: 4,
        companionUrl: '/',
    }).on('complete', (result) => {
        this.testing = 'success';
        console.log('successful files:', result.successful);
        console.log('failed files:', result.failed);
    }),
}
```

I'm trying to update my Vue component's data now by using Uppy's [complete event](https://uppy.io/docs/uppy/#complete), but "this" is not defined. I'm not quite sure how to access "this" from here.

Any idea how to go about doing this?

---

Update

After posting this, I found a solution that works. I'm hesitant with this solution though as it seemed too easy.

If no one provides a better solution, I'll add this as the answer.

```js
// Uppy Instance
uppy: function() {
    return new Uppy({
        logger: Uppy.debugLogger
    }).use(AwsS3Multipart, {
        limit: 4,
        companionUrl: '/',
    }).on('complete', (result) => {
        this.testing = 'success';
        console.log('successful files:', result.successful);
        console.log('failed files:', result.failed);
    })
},
```

Comment: Seems correct. A function is needed if we want access to this Vue instance. The original example was an arrow function, which doesn't provide access to the Vue instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following the Uppy docs and instantiating the Uppy instance with an arrow function, `this` no longer seems to refer to the Vue. This makes it so that accessing `this.method()`, or `this.variable`, etc. no longer works.

My solution was to change the Uppy instantiation from an arrow function to a regular function. I believe this causes `this` to refer to the global instance, but I don't have a solid understanding of `this`, so take what I say with a grain of salt.

I changed this:

```js
computed: {
    uppy: () => new Uppy()
}
```

To this:

```js
computed: {
    uppy: function() { return new Uppy() }
}
```